# Type is System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[MyClass] in my lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I have a problem with `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[MyClass]`

My expression returns `null`, but it shouldn't:

- `myCustomList.Where(x => x.bType != null && x.bType is
  IEnumerable<T>).FirstOrDefault();`

My AddWatch shows me:

- For `T`: `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass>`
- For `x.bType`:
  `{System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[MyClass]}` and    `dynamic
  {System.RuntimeType}` as the `Type`
- `x.bType is IEnumerable<T>` returns `false`.
- `x.bType != null` returns `true`.

`x.bType` is a property and has typically the value of`typeof(IEnumerable<MyClass>))`.

**UPDATED**

I changed my expression to `...x.bType == typeof(IEnumerable<T>)..`.

The `x.bType` shows in red color `{System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[MyClass]}` it seems that he can not convert `List<MyClass>` to `IEnumerable<MyClass>` ?! , because I see an(if I open `x.bType`) `System.InvalidOperationException` for `x.bType.DeclaringMethod`,`x.bType.GenericParameterAttributes` and `x.bType.GenericParameterPosition`

What did I do wrong ?

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to all and especially to @Wilko van der Veen  , this solved my problem: `x.bType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))`, but maybe there is a solution without reflection, because relfection is not that performant in my case ?!

Comment: At least show how bType is set.

Comment: note: `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[MyClass]` is a string and a result of `ToString()` method, called on `IEnumerable<MyClass>` type (debugger calls it to display information about variable). so the real thing is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyClass>`

Comment: @Henk Holterman `bType =typeof(IEnumerable<MyClass>)`. thank you for helping

Comment: You must create a [mcve].

Comment: updated my post, please have a look again

Comment: typeof(IEnumerable<MyClass>) isn't equal to typeof(List<MyClass>). That said, its just right.

Comment: Isnt it possible, to check with a generic T of IEnumerable<MyClass> istead of List<MyClass> ? If yes, then, I think that would be the best way. Your updated Expression for that case is in my Answer below. If that isn't possible, i have no Idea =/

Comment: updated my post, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a certain class implements a certain interface via reflection:

list.Where(l => l.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable<>))

this checks if the type is assignable from the generic IEnumerable class.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it `x.bType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't check a type with is. You have to go with btype == typeof(...)

```
x.bType == typeof(IEnumerable<T>)
```

**EDIT:**
Oh, just realized, that because your T is typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List), this can't work. 
*Itn't it possible, to change the part where you set your bType from
    btype = typeof(List)
to
    btype = typeof(IEnumerable)
and the Expression-Part of the typecheck to 
    x.btype == typeof(T)*

The full Expression then looks like the following:

```
myCustomList.Where(x => x.bType != null && x.bType == typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault()
```

**EDIT2:** Damn Sorry, i need more coffee, so forget the italic part (maybe i will delete i later). I was thinking about your Generic T.

And i really meant:
Isnt it possible, to check with a generic T of IEnumerable istead of List